# ReSharper Abbreviations List: Where can I modify it?

Tags: resharper

I am using ReSharper 4.5, and what often happens when I am converting explicit properties into auto-properties, is that I will accidentally chose "Add XX to abbreviations list".

Ie: I want to convert CustomerID into an autoproperty, but due to quick butterfingers, I will accidentally add "ID" to the abbreviations list instead, which I don't want to do. (I want the naming rules to use "Id" instead of "ID").

**Where can I find and modify the list of custom abbreviations in ReSharper 4.5??**

Answer (score 107, accepted):

In Resharper 5. see answer below.

-In Resharper 4 use Resharper/Options/Languages/Common/Naming Style
Choose the radio "Override common settings"
this enables the button "Manage Abbreviations"

For a specific language

- Resharper/Options/Languages/C#/C# Naming Style
- Resharper/Options/Languages/VB/VB Naming Style

Comment: Thanks!  Don't know why I couldn't find it myself.

Comment: Can't find them there, the dialog seems cut short on Win7/Vs2008

Comment: The "Manage Abbreviations" button is cut off a bit with Win7/VS2008. I was able to click the top of the button, though.  If you can't, click in the grid for "User defined naming rules", press tab three times, then hit the spacebar. That focuses and hits the "Manage abbreviations..." button.

Comment: Just an update that in VS 2010 with ReSharper 6.1 the list of abbreviations now appears under ReSharper/Options/Code Editing/C#/C# Naming Style/Advanced Settings - at the bottom of the panel is a text area with a space-separated list of uppercase abbreviations. This took me a while to locate, thought it might be helpful to others :)

Comment: Though it seems to only understand 2 letters.  ID is OK, SS is OK, SSM (which is what I actually want to use) is not.

Answer (score 51):

In Resharper 7.x it's different than v6.0, its under the specific Language,
for me Resharper/Options/C#/C# Naming Style/Advanced settings
at the bottom of which are a list of space separated abbreviations.

Here's jetbrains (outdated?) site which details (I think the 6.x way of doing it?)
http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp50/Coding_Assistance__Naming_Style.html#dynaProc3

Comment: Resharper 8.x follows the same way as 7.x.

Comment: Resharper 9 is basically the same except there's an added `Code Editing` section between `Options` and `C#` for me.

Answer (score 27):

In the 5.0 beta, it's similar

ReSharper/Options/Languages/Naming Style/Advanced Settings...

Then there's a box at the bottom called "Edit abbreviations as plain text"

Answer (score 25):

In Resharper 6, it's almost the same as 5...

ReSharper/Options/Languages/Naming Style/Advanced Settings...

Then the box at the bottom is called "Abbreviations as plain text (UPPER CASE only):"

Comment: Thank you so much! It's the same in 8.1 as well. This was driving me nuts!

Answer (score 25):

In Resharper 6.1 (beta) its slightly different to v6.0, its under

ReSharper/Options/Code Editing/C#/C# Naming Style/Advanced Settings

Then the box at the bottom is called "Abbreviations as plain text (UPPER CASE only):"

Comment: This is also true for Resharper 7

Comment: This is also true for Resharper 8

Answer (score 9):

For ReSharper 2016 / 2017 this can be found under

`ReSharper` >> `Options` >> `Code Editing` >> `C#/VisualBasic.net` >> `Naming Style` >> `Advanced Settings...` >> `Here you will find abbreviations`

Depending on the language you will find it under different places..

Somtimes you will find it under
`ReSharper` >> `Options` >> `Code Editing` >> `{language}` >> `Naming Style` >> `abbreviations`

Screenshot:
[image: Demonstrated an an Image]

Answer (score 8):

ReSharper 10.0.2 using Visual Studio 2015

`ReSharper > Options > Code Editing > C# > Naming Style`

Click `Advanced settings` to open the `Advanced Naming Settings` window.

Modify the text box `Abbreviations`

Answer (score 3):

ReSharper 9.2: 
RESHARPER/Options/C#/Naming Style/Advanced settings

Answer (score 2):

In resharper 5.X versions, please use "Reset to Defaults" to remove already added abbreviations.

ReSharper/Options/Code Editing/C#/C# Naming Style/Override to common settings/Reset to Defaults

@user1107632:
2D and 3D are not a valid variable and you are not going to use anyway.

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=24472