# ReSharper naming style for event methods

Tags: c#, resharper

Resharper does not detect if a method has been generated by user or VS. it always highlights event methods generated by VS which have underscore in them (like `button1_Click()` even).

How can I make an exception in this case?

Comment: I don't think you can, since there is no way for Resharper to know that the method has been auto-generated...

Comment: Maybe this can help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769882/resharper-abbreviations-list-where-can-i-modify-it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On `ReSharper | Options | Languages | C# | Naming Style` check Override common settings, then click on Advanced settings.

Then you should have this on Event subscription on fields : `$object$_$event$` . Press OK on both windows and you are good to go.